# JavaScript query handling

Tags: javascript, c++, npapi

I use NPAPI in my application and connecting by this interface to the Flash Player plugin. How i must handle next requests, sended from plugin by calling `NPN_GetUrl`:

- `javascript:top.location+"__flashplugin_unique__"`
- `javascript:window.location+"__flashplugin_unique__"`

P. S. In both cases second param of `NPN_GetUrl` - type `const char*` named "window" (or "target") is `NULL`.

Comment: I've read your question 5 times and I have no clue what you're asking

Comment: What i must to do when i recieve this requests from Adobe Flash Player plugin, ie what i must to do when my function `NPN_GetUrl()`, pointer to which i give to the plugin, is called by plugin and income variables is: `const char* url == javascript:top.location+"__flashplugin_unique__"` and `const char* window == NULL`. And second call variables is: `const char* url == javascript:window.location+"__flashplugin_unique__"` and `const char* window == NULL`?

Comment: I guess this is about embedding Flash in your application? What happened to the ActiveX embedding approach?

Comment: ActiveX through NPAPI? What's the difference? Or ActiveX through MFC+ActiveControl? How i can monitoring all network activity of ActiveX when it opening Shockwave Flash files?

Comment: Embedding ActiveX control, it was suggested to you in another question. Not sure about the monitoring, why not ask a question on it?